# 'Runnable' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java

I'm like totally new to this world. I didn't know what's wrong with what I'm trying to put into my code because it looks fine. I know that looks doesn't have a correlation with its functionality.
Any help would be appreciated.

My code look like this:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.util.Objects;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        new Handler(). postDelayed(new Runnable());

    }
}
```

Comment: `new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run(){

   }
}` shouldnt the runnable look like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a 'new Runnable()' since Runnable is not a class, it's an interface.

[Link to documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)

You have to define a class that implements the Runnable interface. It can be an anonymous class:

```
new Runnable() {
    void run() {
      // here do whatever you're intending to do
    }
};
```

Note the 'do whatever' comment. The point of having a Runnable is to have it do some work, so even without your current error, you haven't said what work there is to be done.

Comment: wow. this was my first post btw. thank you very much for replying. maybe I should read more like article you sent. may god bless you!

Comment: You may find a tutorial easier to approach than the reference documentation. I don't have any suggestions for a tutorial though.  Google around, ask your friends, whatever.

Comment: Note that since Android now does desugaring even on API levels below Java 8, lambdas are almost always the better choice.

Comment: Try this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html). This resource is my go-to for anyone asking a question about fundamentals. Bookmark it, use it and then tell a friend.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  maybe, but I think I'd advise against it for a raw beginner.  Explicitness is sometimes better.